# Gracefully handling missing arguments when using Laravel RESTful Controllers

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I am learning Laravel and have run into a problem handling missing arguments[, which has also been explained here](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers). However, the solution(s) focus primarily on named routes, but am using RESTful controllers.

TL;DR Is there some elegant solution to handle missing arguments on all of a given controller's methods without naming each one?

### Route

```
Route::controller('accounts', 'AccountsController');
```

### Controller

Here is a sample controller method...where the "example.com/accounts/profile/1" works, but "example.com/accounts/profile/" [with or without the trailing slash] will throw an exception. "ErrorException: Missing argument 1 for AccountsController::getProfile()"

```
public function getProfile($id)
{
    $account = DB::table('accounts')->where('id', $id)->first();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('account.profile', array('account' => $account));
}
```

### One Attempted Solution (Doesn't work)

I've also tried this ↓ , which was a promising-looking suggestion from another question. However, it also does not work.

```
public function getProfile($id = NULL)
{
    if ($id = NULL)
    {
        return Redirect::to('accounts');
    } else {
        $account = DB::table('accounts')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $this->layout->content = View::make('account.profile', array('account' => $account));
    }
}
```

### Other Solution (Works, but is tedious)

I know that using named routes, such as the one below , to cover all of the holes will work, but this seems like such an un-elegant solution! (especially considering the suuuuper tedious process of naming all of the routes for all of the controllers that we are planning on using)

```
Route::get('/accounts/profile', 'AccountsController@missingMethod');
```

### So....

What do you all think? Is there some elegant solution to handle missing arguments on all of a given controller's methods without naming each one?

Comment: using a default paramter should work, why isn't it? ah... the if statement is using an assignment operator instead of comparison, change if($id= NULL) to if ($id == NULL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default parameter option should work aside from a minor and very commonly uncaught error in php.. You're using the assignment operator in your conditional. Use

```
if($id == NULL)
```

instead of

```
 if($id = NULL)
```

or if you like

```
if(is_null($id) )
```

One of the tragedies of a dynamically typed language. Gets me more frequently than I care to admit.

Comment: This works. Wow, I was not expecting this to be just that easy. Thanks a bunch!

I guess I should have mentioned that I am also new to programming in general (6 mo in). So, I'll make sure to watch out for this in my other php endeavors.